# How can I inline CSS Style the border of a radio button that has a custom image applied

Tags: php, css, radio-button, inline-styles

I have a php file with a radio form input. I am using css to replace the radio button with a custom image, **and put a border around the custom image, if the radio button is 'checked'** (see /* CHECKED STYLES */ in css below).

php:

```
$border_col = '#006400;';
echo '
<label>
   <input 
      type="radio" 
      name="ava_select" 
      value="' . $ava_row["ID"] . '" 
      class="img_radio" 
      ';
      if ($row["avatar"]==$ava_row["ID"]) {
         echo ' checked="checked" ';    
      }
      echo '
   >
   <img 
      src="img/profile/' . $ava_row["img"] . '" 
      alt="Avatar" 
      class="img-fluid rounded"
   >
</label> 
';
```

css:

```
/* for replacing radio inputs on forms to images */
/* HIDE RADIO */
.img_radio {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* IMAGE STYLES */
.img_radio + img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* CHECKED STYLES */
.img_radio:checked + img {
  outline: 4px solid #006400;
}
```

I would like to change the color of the outline applied by css (currently #006400;) using a php variable ($border_col). I would therefore like to use inline css to apply the styling for '.img_radio:checked + img', so that I can swap out the line color dynamically, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

I'm somewhat familiar with inline styling for simpler use-cases, however I have tried multiple variations without success. The problem seems to be referencing the state of the radio button (i.e. checked + img) inline.

As per the advice provided by Chris Haas in comments, I tried to implement some CSS variables as follows:

```
css:

/* CHECKED STYLES */
.img_radio:checked + img {
  /*outline: 4px solid #006400;*/
  outline-color: var(--img_radio-outline_color, red);
  outline-style: var(--img_radio-outline_style, solid);
  outline-width: var(--img_radio-outline_width, 4px);
}


html:

<label>
    <input 
        type="radio" 
        name="ava_select" 
        value="10" 
        class="img_radio" 
        style="
            --img_radio-outline_color: blue;
            --img_radio-outline_width: 4px;
            --img_radio-outline_style: solid;
        "
        checked="checked"
    >
    <img 
        src="img/profile/f10.png" 
        alt="Avatar" 
        class="img-fluid rounded"
    >
</label>
```

I was hoping this would result in a blue solid line, however the border on the 'checked' image is remaining red.

Comment: Where's the variable in your PHP code associated with a color?

Comment: This feels like a good case for CSS custom properties/variables, which you can set via PHP: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: @John I didn't think it was relevant so did not include it. I've updated my code snippet

Comment: @Chris Haas Thanks for this, I'll do some reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick demo of CSS custom properties. You use the `var()` function with a property name and an optional default value, just in case nothing is set, which I'd strongly recommend using for debugging purposes. You can then set that property over and over again and it will apply to the local scope, which in this case is that specific instance of that div.

```
<style>
    .something {
        width: 100px;
        aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
        background-color: var(--something-bg-color, red);
        display: grid;
        place-content: center;
    }
</style>
<div class="something">
    default
</div>
<?php foreach (['purple', 'blue', 'yellow'] as $color): ?>
    <div class="something" style="--something-bg-color: <?php echo $color; ?>">
        <?php echo $color; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which produces:

[image]

**Edit**

Using your code, and moving it to the label it would look like this:

```
<label
        style="
            --img_radio-outline_color: blue;
            --img_radio-outline_width: 4px;
            --img_radio-outline_style: solid;
        "
>
    <input 
        type="radio" 
        name="ava_select" 
        value="10" 
        class="img_radio"
        checked="checked"
    >
    <img 
        src="img/profile/f10.png" 
        alt="Avatar" 
        class="img-fluid rounded"
    >
</label>
```

Comment: Great explanation, makes perfect sense. Unfortunately I have a few hours of work to finish before I can try this, but I will accept the answer this evening. Many thanks!

Comment: Well my first attempt at implementing your advice did not go well. I've added my attempt to my question in case you can see any obvious glaring problems, but I will keep working on it myself.

Comment: @SlickRed, this is where scoping comes in. As you've written it, the variable is being set on the `<input>` tag and is also available to all its decedents (if applicable). Your `<img>` is adjacent to it, however, so it can't see that scope. My recommendation would be to set this on the `<label>` tag since that contains the `<img>` tag, although you could instead just set it on the `<img>` tag, too.

Comment: I think I follow, but if I apply the styling to the <label> instead of the <input>, won't I lose access to the 'checked' property of the <input>? In other words, won't this be applied to ALL <labels> containing an <input>, instead of ONLY <labels> containing a CHECKED <input>?

Actually I suppose I could use javascript to change the class of the label (to something with a border) when the input is selected...

Comment: I've updated my answer with another sample. You move the properties to the parent node, but you keep the checked stuff on the input.

Comment: However, after seeing what you are more specifically doing I'm wondering if CSS properties are a good fit. Do you actually need to support an unlimited number of colors on the server-side, or just a couple? The latter is much more common and I'd just use some specific class selectors to handle this instead, if that's the case

Comment: Yeah just a few colors depending on the status of the logged in user, and I think you're right that setting up a few class selectors and defining which class is being used via php is the better approach. I'm still going to accept your answer though as it certainly addresses my original problem and I learned a lot. Thanks again for your time.